# Factor $x^2+2x+2$ in $\mathbb{F}_3/(x^2+1)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

I am asked to find two roots of $x^2+2x+2$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ (the Kronecker construction). The elements of that field are (equivalence classes of) constant or linear polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, so I should be able to just write $x^2+2x+2=(nx+m)(px+q)$ and, under equivalence given by the kernel $x^2+1=0$, find that this is $x^2+2x+2$. But after much scratch-paper work (checking every combination by hand) I have only succeeded in walking myself in circles. I would appreciate if someone could walk me through this problem.

(I am mainly confused by, since $x^2=-1$, isn't $x^2+2x+2=2x+1$? So how can there be two roots?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the name $x$ for both the indeterminate of the polynomial and the indeterminate of the field extension is just asking for trouble.

So let's factor $y^2+2y+2$ in $\Bbb F_3[x]/(x^2+1)$.

$y^2+2y+2 = (y+1)^2+1 = (y+1)^2 - x^2 = (y+1-x)(y+1+x)$

Comment: Ah. I did not realize that was my trouble. Thank you for clearing this up. Although I would maybe write it as $(y+(1-x))(y+(1+x))$ for clarity.